# Compute a hessian matrix on a image?

Tags: image, image-processing

Is it possible for Mathmatica to load a gray image and apply a hessian matrix on it?... It used image processing to find good features.

Comment: Is "Apply a Hessian" the same as "Calculate the second derivatives matrices"?

Comment: yes @belisarius

Comment: It looks like you might need [ImageFilter](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageFilter.html), but there are also many [built in filters](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/FeatureDetection.html) that may do what you want.

Answer (score 5):

I normally use something like this:

```
img = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Airport"}];

{h[xx], h[xy], h[yy]} = 
  GaussianFilter[ImageData[img], 5, #] & /@ {{0, 2}, {1, 1}, {2, 0}};
```

(Note: This line can be written much more tersely. But this way it should be clear what's going on: We're applying a Gaussian derivative filter, to get the 2nd order derivatives of the image, and assign the 3 results to the 3 variables `h[xx]`, `h[xy]` and `h[yy]`.

Now, `h[xx], h[xy], h[yy]` contain the 3 independent components of the Hessian at each pixel.

Then you can do symbolic calculations using simliar symbols, e.g. to calculate the eigenvalues of a generic symmetric 2x2 matrix:

```
eigenvalues = FullSimplify@Eigenvalues[{{m[xx], m[xy]}, {m[xy], m[yy]}}]
```

> $\left\{\frac{1}{2} \left(-\sqrt{(m(\text{xx})-m(\text{yy}))^2+4 m(\text{xy})^2}+m(\text{xx})+m(\text{yy})\right),\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{(m(\text{xx})-m(\text{yy}))^2+4 m(\text{xy})^2}+m(\text{xx})+m(\text{yy})\right)\right\}$

And then simply replace `m` with `h` in the symbolic result to apply it to the image Hessian:

```
imgEigenvalues = eigenvalues /. m -> h;
```

Now `imgEigenvalues` contains a 2d array for each of the two eigenvalues of the Hessian at every pixel:

```
GraphicsRow[Image /@ Rescale[imgEigenvalues]]
```

[image]

You can use that to search for image features, e.g. "where is the second eigenvalue larger than some value":

```
HighlightImage[img, Binarize[Image[imgEigenvalues[[2]]], 0.01]]
```

[image]

Comment: Can you not just use `DerivativeFilter` or `GradientFilter` ? I believe there's also an example in the documentation:
`ridgeFilter[img_, s_: 1] := Module[{data = ImageData@img, Lxx,Lxy, Lyy},{Lxx, Lxy, Lyy} = DerivativeFilter[data, {{0, 2}, {1, 1}, {2,0}},s];Image[Chop[s^(3/2)/2 (Sqrt[(Lxx - Lyy)^2 + 4 Lxy^2] - Lxx - Lyy)]]]`

Comment: @Histograms: As far as I understand the documentation, `GradientFilter` basically uses `GaussianFilter`, and it can only calculate the 1st derivative. You could use `DerivativeFilter`, of course. I generally start with `GaussianFilter`, as it's in some sense the most "natural" kernel and has (at least theoretically) certain unique advantages, especially if you calculate multiple scales. (The reasoning is too long for a comment, and honestly, I'd have to look most of it up myself, but I can give references if you're interested.)

Comment: Would it be possible mark those which is above a certain threshold for both eigenvalues?..

Comment: @SURF: Sure, you could use e.g. `minEigenvalue = MapThread[Min, imgEigenvalues, 2];` to calculate the per-pixel min of the two eigenvalues, then binarize the result that.

Comment: Could these values also be calculated for different scales?...
such as the input image still is the same, but the hessian is calculated on different scales..

Comment: @SURF: Of course, just pack the whole thing in a function that takes the scale parameter (second parameter to `GaussianFilter`) as a parameter and call that with a range of values (using `Table` or `Array`). Or use `Manipulate` to see the effect of scale interactively.